# Ways to speed up a divorce?

Tags: rules-of-court, divorce, family-law, georgia

Situation:

One spouse is interested in getting the divorce over with quickly, and the other spouse is interested in going very slowly.  The interest in going slowly is because the status quo is much more generous financially and otherwise than the divorce decree will be.  (This last statement assumes that the GAL report is accepted by the court as the basis for the final decree, which is likely.)  There is a young child involved.

One attorney seems to have no ideas on how to make the case move along quickly (or at all), while the other attorney has many, innovative delaying tactics.

What ways are there to get the divorce court (in Georgia) to tell both sides to make progress (e.g., to complete the mandatory mediation by a certain date)?

Update: Is a court likely to modify the original (now more than 1/2 year old) temporary court order (on custody) based on the GAL report?

Comment: Not legal advice, but wouldn't it make sense for the financially disadvantaged party to take steps to (at least temporarily) to change the status quo so as to correct the imbalance and provide a carrot and stick to get the other party moving?    Also, maybe do some shopping for another attorney - come to think of it, they could go hand in hand - a more expensive attorne could (a) speed things up, (b) cost more whereby reducing the financial difference and (c) possibly provide a better settlement.

Comment: @davidgo  Carrots do not work well when there is much hate and unrealistic expectations.  Current attorney is plenty expensive.